# how to count composite primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, composite-key

I have a table the primary key of which is a composite formed on 3 columns:

```
userID      FK of users table  
itemID      FK of items table
itemType    FK of itemtypes table
```

**Primary Key is combination of (userID, itemID, itemType )**

Assume: itemID 1 is a BALL, and itemType 1 is BLACK COLOR.
so in below example,

```
User 1 is selecting a BALL which is BLACK
User 2 is selecting a BALL which is WHITE
User 3 is selecting a BALL which is BLACK


+------+------+--------+
|userID|itemID|itemType| 
+------+------+--------+
|   1  |  1   |   1    |
+------+------+--------+
|   2  |  1   |   2    |
+------+------+--------+
|   3  |  1   |   1    |
```

Now I want to count ALL users which selected a BLACK BALL, How can I count the primary key of this table which is composite

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count ALL users which selected a BLACK BALL, try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(userID)
FROM table1
WHERE itemID = 1 AND itemType = 1
```

I am not sure what you mean by "How can I count the primary key of this table"

Comment: primary key of this table is combination of ( userID, itemID, itemType ), so isn't anyway to count primary key ?

Comment: I dont see any need to count the primary key. Using the above query, you can get the count of users with a specific itemID and itemType.

Answer (score 4):

I solved for this by concating the composite key, and counting that:

```
SELECT COUNT( CONCAT(userID, '-', itemID, '-', itemType) ) FROM myTable
```